# Vietnam visa requirements for UK citizens

Tags: visas, uk-citizens, vietnam

Do I need a visa for Vietnam if I arrive in July 2018? I can only find information that states no visa is required for UK citizens arriving in Vietnam before 30 June 2018. I hold a full UK passport.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this information is still useful for you but UK citizen can enter Vietnam under visa exemption for 15 days as long as meeting 2 conditions:
- The passports are valid in at least 6 months
- The gap 30 days between 2 free visa visits are required
Or if you want to stay longer in Vietnam, you need to apply for a visa. You can use [our service (I work for them in customer service) to apply for visa on arrival](https://www.vietnam-visa.org.vn). It's very quick and convenient.

Comment: Are you associated with the site? It's ok, but you do need to declare it, or risk having the answer removed.

Comment: Yes, I'm associated with this site. I'm in customer service department of this service. I just want to introduce our service to those who need Vietnam visa. We are reputable and trustful. All information that provided is official and correct. Hope you don't remove our comment. Thanks for your understand.

Answer (score 1):

No one knows - it depends on whether the visa exemption gets extended. The best way to find out the likelihood of this is contacting the Vietnamese MFA.

Or, to be safe, you can just get an [e-visa](https://evisa.xuatnhapcanh.gov.vn/trang-chu-ttdt)

Answer (score 0):

A visa is definitely required if you want to stay more than 10 days and the immigration police are really unfriendly so if you have a return ticket a month ahead you'll have to cough up.  You're supposed to have a "letter of introduction" I'm in the back of a cab now or I'd give you a link but Vietnam Visa Company will get you a month / 3 month whatever. If you're planning to go in and out regularly cough up for a multiple entry visa, I think mine was $99. Enjoy your trip, it's a fabulous country.

Comment: 15 days, not 10, and no, a letter of imvitation is npt required, except possibly for Business visits